# Reload Webpage when timeout Mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

Hi guys my code is basically used to check a number of links i've gave to find certain tags in the webpage. Once found it will then give me back the links that i've gave. However, sometimes mechanize will get stuck forever trying to open/read the page unless i've set a timeout. Are they any ways to reload/retry the webpage upon time out?

```
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import time
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import socket


br = Browser()

with open("url.txt", 'r+') as f:
lines = f.read().splitlines()

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

no_stock = []
for i in tqdm(lines):
    r = br.open(i, timeout=200)
    r = r.read()
    done = False
    tries = 3
    while tries and not done:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
            done = True # exit the loop
        except:
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
    if not done:
        print('Failed for {}'.format(i))
        continue # skip this and continue with the next
    table = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "empty_result"})
    results = soup.find_all('strong', style = 'color: red;')
    if table or results:
        no_stock.append(i)
```

Updated error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_response.py", line 190, in read
    self.__cache.write(self.wrapped.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 355, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 587, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 656, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 702, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catch the `socket.timeout` exception and retry there:

```
try:
    # first try
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
except socket.timeout:
    # try a second time
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
```

---

You can even try many times, and if a line fails, continue with the next:

```
for i in tqdm(lines):
    r = br.open(i, timeout=200)
    r = r.read()
    done = False
    tries = 3
    while tries and not done:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
            done = True # exit the loop
        except: # just catch any error
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
    if not done:
        print('Failed for {}'.format(i))
        continue # skip this and continue with the next
    table = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "empty_result"})
    results = soup.find_all('strong', style = 'color: red;')
    if table or results:
        no_stock.append(i)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm still very new in python. i've previously thought of your idea and looked up on socket timeout with try statements but i've no idea how to combine it with my "for" statements when timeout occurs. care to give some guidance?

Comment: @Jeof, have a look at the new example, I think is more like you will need, the program do not stop on error, and can retry every line many times.

Comment: thanks for the tips, i've tried running it again. after awhile i had this error which i'v ejust updated on top

Comment: i've removed the error to catch anything, now it produces a different results, i've updated my post for you to have a look

Comment: May be one of those lines is not a correctly formed URL. Hope my answer helped you on your original question.

Comment: Yes it does ! thanks buddy ur the man. on the other hand, do you think if this code can be modified to multithreading/multiprocessing as i've over 1000 links to check hence it will take quite awhile to do so. i'm fairly new to multiprocessing so i'm not sure if I/O bounded will improve its processing speed

Comment: Hi, multiprocessing surely will improve your performance in this case. You should move the code currently inside the 'for' loop into a function, the function should receive 1 parameter: the url. Then you create a multiprocessing.Pool to create a pool and pass the lines to the pool.

Comment: You can also try multithreading, for this problem the CPU is not used with high intensity, probably you will not have much problems with the GIL.

Comment: Hi Camilo yes i've thought of multi processing. I've currently opened a new thread for this and i got stuck in a HTTP 503 error return. I wondered what went wrong. Do you mind to help me take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989478/multiprocessing-in-python-beautifulsoup-issues