# Multiprocessing in python/beautifulsoup issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, mechanize, python-multiprocessing

Hi guys i'm fairly new in python. what i'm trying to do is to move my old code into multiprocessing however i'm facing some errors that i hope anyone could help me out. My code is used to check a few thousand links given in a text form to check for certain tags. Once found it will output it to me. Due to the reason i have a few thousand links to check, speed is an issue and hence the need for me to move to multi processing.

Update: i'm having return errors of HTTP 503 errors. Am i sending too much request or am i missin gout something?

Multiprocessing code:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import socket
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

no_stock = []

def main(lines):
    done = False
    tries = 1
    while tries and not done:
        try:
            r = br.open(lines, timeout=15)
            r = r.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
            done = True # exit the loop
        except socket.timeout:
            print('Failed socket retrying')
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
        except Exception as e: 
            print '%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e)
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
    if not done:
        print('Failed for {}\n'.format(lines))
    table = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "empty_result"})
    results = soup.find_all('strong', style = 'color: red;')
    if table or results:
        no_stock.append(lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = br.open('http://www.randomweb.com/') #avoid redirection
    fileName = "url.txt"
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    with open(fileName, "r+") as f:
        lines = pool.map(main, f)
    with open('no_stock.txt','w') as f :
        f.write('No. of out of stock items : '+str(len(no_stock))+'\n'+'\n')
    for i in no_stock:
        f.write(i + '\n')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 43, in <module>
    lines = pool.map(main, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment
```

my txt file is something like this:-

```
http://www.randomweb.com/item.htm?uuid=44733096229
http://www.randomweb.com/item.htm?uuid=4473309622789
http://www.randomweb.com/item.htm?uuid=447330962291
....etc
```

Comment: You need to add your traceback(s) to the main post.

Comment: Hi Morgan, thanks for the reply but i do not quite get your meaning. Could you explain abit more?

Comment: You need to add to add the errors you're getting to your main post.

Comment: ah ok thanks! just added (:

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Look at the line right above that. (`def main():`.)

Comment: I've tried to fix up the indentation. Could you run it again and tell us what happens?

Comment: Annnnnddd... it's broken again.

Comment: @AidanKane The issue is OPs indentation. Don't fix it.

Comment: I rolled back the indentation changes in the edit.  Whitespace matters in Python -- if you edit the asker's indentation, it's a different question.  To be sure: editing the spacing in the question is doing the reverse of helping.

Comment: @AidanKane: _Sometimes_ bad indentation in a question is just due to a mistake in copy & pasting, but you _really_ need to verify with the OP that the code in their code block doesn't match what's in their editor before fiddling with it. And in most cases it's probably better to coach them into fixing it themself so they don't mess it up next time. But thanks for trying to be helpful.

Comment: hi guys, i've just fixed the indentation, my bad about that. i'm having a new error now. Do you guys mind to take a quick look for me?

Comment: FWIW, there are still indentation problems in your "Old code"  code block. (And if there's an error message you need to paste it into your question (in a code block)).

Comment: You're reading the file in as a binary file `'rb'`. Try reading it in as a text file `'r'`

Comment: @MorganThrapp, i've tried it but the error is still showing the same

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah - I was being a bit silly. I just assumed that there were going to be *real* errors in the multiprocessing code so was just trying to skip to that part. Brainfreeze, my bad.

Comment: @PM2Ring hi pm, i could run the old code without any problems, probably due to copy pasting errors. i will repaste it over again

Comment: @Jeof: I can't really help you with your question because I don't use the mechanize, bs4, tqdm, or multiprocessing modules. But you'll get more info from your program if you get rid of that unnamed `except:` clause that contains `print('Random fail retrying')` and replace it with something like: `except Exception as e:` `print '%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e)`

Comment: @PM2Ring cheers for the tips i will do as per your advice and see what we can do to fix it. many thanks

Comment: @AidanKane, i've just did a quick fix on the indentation and some quick fix/edit on the code, it is now giving me a new error from the traceback, any tips for this issue? thx for ur help

Comment: @PM2Ring, followed your advice and i got back an error HTTP503 error. Am i parsing too much request that it blocked me out? Or is it due to my user agent issues? hmmm

Comment: @Jeof are you willing to use different tech (say gevent and requests)? Not that there's anything wrong with your approach - just that I don't have the time to pick through it and gevent is probably a better fit (in this case).

Comment: @AidanKane yes i do not mind at all so long as it works. I've tried to look into gevent but i must say it has not alot of examples for me to refer to. Pretty limited on the net. Any tips?

Comment: How about a lib that rolls them both together :-) https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: @AidanKane thanks for that, i'm reading up on it. Also seems like you and i are in the same timezone! i was thinking if you got an email or somewhat that you can guide me further as the comment section is getting really long

Comment: Sure thing. Username @ that google based email service.

Comment: @AidanKane sent you an email. Not sure if i hit the jackpot, do let me know :)

Answer (score -1):

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import socket
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # This is a thread-based Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

br = Browser()

no_stock = []

def main(line):
    done = False
    tries = 3
    while tries and not done:
        try:
            r = br.open(line, timeout=15)
            r = r.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
            done = True # exit the loop
        except socket.timeout:
            print('Failed socket retrying')
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
        except:
            print('Random fail retrying')
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
            tries -= 1 # to exit when tries == 0
    if not done:
        print('Failed for {}\n'.format(i))
    table = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "empty_result"})
    results = soup.find_all('strong', style = 'color: red;')
    if table or results:
        no_stock.append(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileName = "url.txt"
    pool = Pool(cpu_count() * 2)  # Creates a Pool with cpu_count * 2 threads.
    with open(fileName, "rb") as f:
        lines = pool.map(main, f)
    with open('no_stock.txt','w') as f :
        f.write('No. of out of stock items : '+str(len(no_stock))+'\n'+'\n')
    for i in no_stock:
        f.write(i + '\n')
```

pool.map takes two parameters, the fist is a function(in your code, is main), the other is an iterable, each item of iterable will be a parameter of the function(in your code, is each line of the file)

Comment: thanks for the tips, i've did abit of fix  for the iterable on the other parts however the code seems not to be working. it is giving me <class 'mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper'> error

Comment: can you post the full traceback

Comment: why do you need tqdm? the value of lines passed in main is one line of the file, which responds to a web site, thus, you can just use "lines" to browser open

Comment: i'm using tqdm just to let me know how is the progress going.This is because sometimes my program gets stucked in the middle. Hence a reference for me. i've updated the traceback at my main post with ur code provided

Comment: i've set my variable "soup" to global and it updates me with another error which i'm lost